# Decorate input field with textarea-like style

Tags: html, css, input

Maybe it's a strange question, but is it possible to decorate the input field bottom-right corner to have these two narrow lines, which are default in the textarea field? So it's only about the decoration, no need for the same functionality.

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxqpXK

```css
input {
      border-top: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Input text">
    
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why do not you use textarea instead of input text?

Comment: this is how it's printed in the form, so I'm just trying to achieve the same style with these dashes..did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes only the decoration, sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: If you refer to the resize handle this is something that every browser displays differently and you'd have a hard time replicating it for each and every case.

Comment: If you only want the decoration is enough adding a background-image with appropriate background-position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.resizable-input {
    /* make resizable */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    resize: horizontal;
    display: inline-block;

    /* no extra spaces */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
  
    /* default widths */
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 2em;
    max-width: 30em;
}

/* let <input> assume the size of the wrapper */
.resizable-input > input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

/* add a visible handle */
.resizable-input > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: -16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAJUlEQVR4AcXJRwEAIBAAIPuXxgiOW3xZYzi1Q3Nqh+bUDk1yD9sQaUG/4ehuEAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<span class="resizable-input"><input type="text" /><span>
```

Maybe this could help!! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: It works even with the error (i.e. there is no `.resizable-input > span`). Impressive.

Comment: may I ask to briefly explain .resizeable-input > span and how can I move the image to change its position if possible..? (in my case its a bit below the line) @DeepakVerma

Comment: resizeable-input  > span state that apply resizable-input class property to its child span. and to adjust position of image u can use padding in resizeable-input  > span